# Spring annotation conditionalOnBean not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean

I defined a class with annotation Configuration

```java
    @Configuration
    @AutoConfigureAfter(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class)
    public class EndpointConfiguration {
        @Resource
        private MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint;

        @Bean
        public MetricsFormatEndpoint metricsFormatEndpoint() {
            return new MetricsFormatEndpoint(metricsEndpoint);
        }
    }
```

the MetricsFormatEndpoint works well.

but I use the annotation conditionalOnBean, it doesn't work at all.

```java
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(MetricsEndpoint.class)
    public MetricsFormatEndpoint metricsFormatEndpoint() {
        return new MetricsFormatEndpoint(metricsEndpoint);
    }
```

see the localhost:8080/beans,the spring applicationContext has the bean 'metricsEndpoint',

```
    {"bean":"metricsEndpoint","scope":"singleton",
     "type":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint",
     "resource":"class path resource 
    [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointAutoConfiguration.class]",
    "dependencies":[]}
```

I read the document of the annotation @ConditionalOnBean, it says The class type of bean that should be checked. The condition matches when any of the classes specified is contained in the {@link ApplicationContext}.

who can tell me why

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work at all", what happens? What failure/unexpected behaviour have you seen?

Answer (score 25):

The javadoc for `@ConditionalOnBean` describes it as:

> `Conditional` that only matches when the specified bean classes and/or names are already contained in the `BeanFactory`.

In this case, the key part is "already contained in the `BeanFactory`". Your own configuration classes are considered before any auto-configuration classes. This means that the auto-configuration of the `MetricsEndpoint` bean hasn't happened by the time that your own configuration is checking for its existence and, as a result, your `MetricsFormatEndpoint` bean isn't created.

One approach to take would be to [create your own auto-configuration class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration) for your `MetricsFormatEndpoint` bean and annotate it with `@AutoConfigureAfter(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class)`. That will ensure that its conditions are evaluated after the `MetricsEndpoint` bean has been defined.

Comment: i also try this,@AutoConfigureAfter(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class) ,it doesn't work either.

Comment: `@AutoConfigureAfter` will only work on an auto-configuration class. Did you create your own as I suggested above?

Comment: i add the annotation @AutoConfigureAfter(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class) on the class EndpointConfiguration,it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example of what you describe. I added the FlywayAutoConfiguration class to the spring.factories so the flyway migration is ran before my configuration class but it doesn't when I use AutoConfigureAfter. I have to autowire FlywayMigrationInitializer to ensure it does which I don't like before I do not actually use the bean.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson "Your own configuration classes are considered before any auto-configuration classes''. But then, how is it possible we can inject starter beans into our app's configuration class?

Comment: @Whimusical The answer is in the context of defining bean, not dependency injection. When beans are being defined, your own configuration classes are considered before any auto-configuration classes. When beans are being created and dependencies are being injected, all of the defined beans are considered equally. This allows a bean from auto-configuration to be injected into a an app's own bean or configuration class.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Ahh nice, it makes all sense. Thanks

Comment: If you are trying `@AutoConfigureAfter(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class)` and it does not work, that's because at least in the recent versions, this auto-configuration is not tied to any specific endpoint auto-configurations and does not guarantee that endpoints will be auto-configured after it's done. I faced this problem with `StartupEndpoint` and had to add specifically `@AutoConfigureAfter(StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration.class)` to get it going. And if you have multiple endpoints, yeah, there will be a long list of configs in there.

Answer (score 0):

`ConditionalOnClass` worked as well.

Javadoc said that AutoConfigureAfter should be applied after other `specified auto-configuration` classes.

And ConditionalOnClass matches when the specified classes are on the classpath. I think it's properer