# @ConditionalOnBean does not work with manually registered bean

Tags: java, spring

I have such an issue. On the basis of the database configuration I need to create appropriate beans that will handle whole process. I've figured out that I will try do it in the following way.
First, create the marker bean on the basis of db config .

```
@Configuration
class Dbconfig {
  @Autowired DbRepo dbRepo;
  @Autowired GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;
  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    Config config = dbRepo.findConfiguration();
    if(config.value.equals("test")){
      applicationContext.registerBean("testBean", TestBean.class, TestBean::new);
    }else{ //other steps
  }
}
```

Then, on the basis of this marker bean I will create the proper ones, like:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "testBean")
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = Dbconfig.class)
public class ObjConfig{
//creating proper @Beans
  }
```

But, unfortunately, it does not work. Don’t know why spring does not seem to see this “testBean”. Nevertheless, I have debugged it and I can see this bean exists in BeanFactory  of the Application Context. It also works smoothly with the @DependsOn annotation, then spring can see this bean.
I will appreciate any help or suggestions how to resolve the problem in other way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799855/why-conditionalonbean-doesnt-work

Comment: How have you checked that *registerBean(...)* was called?

Comment: @HarshMishra stackoverflow.com/questions/31799855/…  it's different situation, as beans are not registered manually there. Moreover I've used the @AutoConfigureAfter/Before - it does'n change a thing.

Comment: I think the issue may be in registering the testBean in the @PostConstruct. Take a look at the answer of this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501215/spring-boot-autoconfigure-only-if-bean-javamailsender-exists

Comment: @mentallurg Yes, I did and it was called. I debugged it and it can be found by applicationContext.getBeanDefinition("testBean") or by 
applicationContext.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition("testBean")

Comment: @ederribeiro Thanks, so it seems it cannot be achieved this way.

Answer (score 0):

`@AutoConfigureAfter` will only work on an auto-configuration class and not for manually configured beans. If you were wiring testBean as a `Autowired` bean your code will work. You may try `@ConditionalOnExpression` to inject bean based on an `SpEL` expression.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. A workaround with the `@ConditionalOnExpression` works fine with a bean injection, but as I have a lot of beans I tried to fix this with:
    `@Configuration
    @ConditionalOnExpression ("#{testBean.active == true}")
    public class ObjConfig{
    //config @Beans
    }`
and then I'm getting: `SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'testBean' cannot be found` .. Any clue why?