# @ConditionalOnBean not detecting bean even though it is created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a class annotated with @Configuration and a bean

```
  @Configuration
  public class ExampleServiceConfig {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(value = servicefeature1.enable", havingValue = "true")
  public ExampleServices exampleServices() {
    return new ExampleServices();

  }
```

I then have another service class that depends on the bean above:

```
@ConditionalOnBean(ExampleServices.class)
public class AnotherService{

   @Autowired
   public AnotherService(ExampleServices exampleServices){
      this.exampleServices = exampleServices
   }
}
```

In the spring debug logs, I see the first bean is getting created:

```
2020-02-28 14:08:51.841 DEBUG 18158 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'exampleServices'
```

But the AnotherService() is not getting created:

```
AnotherService:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: x.x.x.ExampleServices; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type x.x.x.ExampleServices (OnBeanCondition)
```

Why is the AnotherService() not getting created even though the ExampleService bean was created successfully?

Also, I see the "did not match" log after the ExampleService bean got created.

Comment: I assume it's a typo that you have parentheses on the class definition: `public class AnotherService(){ ...`, right?

Comment: Probably a duplicate. refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31807548/2984491

Comment: @Varesh, no this is a different problem

Comment: What is `ReplicationExceptionRepositories` - is it some dependency of that class? Does `AnotherService` has more dependencies and annotations than what is currently posted in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think adding `@DependsOn` to the mix could fix your issue. Here is another answer, somewhat similar with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50518946/6908551

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnBean(ExampleServices.class)
@DependsOn("exampleServices")
public class AnotherService {

   @Autowired
   public AnotherService(ExampleServices exampleServices) {
      this.exampleServices = exampleServices
   }
}
```

Comment: DependsOn will force the creation of ExampleServices even though the property condition it depends on evaluates to false